# PostGIS query optimisation

Tags: postgis, sql, query

I have three spatial datasets - mitch_ibra has about 2700 polygons, hev has ~1,200,000 polygons and prop_p1 with about 180,000. For each polygon in mitch_ibra I want to know how many polygons of prop_p1 are inside, with a minimum size of 5ha or overlaps the mitch_ibra polygon by 5ha. Finally I want the number of these polygons intersect polygons from the hev table.

```
WITH region AS
  (SELECT geom
   FROM mitch_ibra
   WHERE sub_name_7 = 'Tingha Plateau'
     AND lscape_nam = 'Dumaresq Channels')

SELECT COUNT(props.id)
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT initprop.id
   FROM
     (SELECT id,geom
      FROM prop_p1
      WHERE st_area(ST_transform(geom,3308))>50000) AS initprop
   JOIN region ON st_intersects(initprop.geom,region.geom),
     (SELECT hev.geom FROM hev JOIN region ON ST_Intersects(hev.geom,region.geom)) AS hevsel
   WHERE CASE
             WHEN ST_Within(initprop.geom,region.geom) THEN ST_Area(ST_Transform(initprop.geom,3308))
             ELSE ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(initprop.geom,region.geom),3308))
         END > 50000
         AND ST_Intersects(initprop.geom,hevsel.geom)) AS props
```

Above is my query so far, which gives me a processing time of about 658s for a region with 1300 polygons selected in the prop_p1 subquery. All have tables have GIST indexes.  How can I optimize my indexes/query to reduce processing time.  Is this as good as I'm going to get? (I have to run this over 300 different selections in the WITH statement)

Comment: Indexes cannot be applied to a CTE. You can use a materialized view instead, or a temp table, or replace references to `region` by the complete query (i.e. remove the CTE)

Comment: Thanks, that actually got me ~ 3.5% decrease in processing time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes cannot be applied to a CTE. You can use a materialized view instead, or a temp table (both with an index), or replace references to `region` by the complete query (i.e. remove the CTE)

Comment: It's a fair bit more complicated than that -- see https://robots.thoughtbot.com/advanced-postgres-performance-tips and https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/. I suspect this query could be much better optimized by removing the CTE (as you suggest) and grouping by sub_name_7 and lscape_nam. There are so many other problems with that query, such as using ST_Transform inside where's inside case statments. Without an EXPLAIN statement you answer is just a guess, and frankly, 3.5% improvement is not that great.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the polygons are at least close to eachother, before checking if they intersect:

```
...JOIN region ON initprop.geom&&region.geom and st_intersects(initprop.geom,region.geom)...
```

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/geometry_overlaps.html

And can you tune your PostGres configuration? Adding work_mem (at least for this session) can do miracles.

Comment: +1 for Postgres config. Note that [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_Intersects.html) includes a bounding box comparison that makes use of the index.

Comment: Adding && bounding box intersection actually decreased performance unfortunately, but i'll have a play around with the tuning - thanks.

Comment: Actually by replacing the st_intersect in the hev, region join with the && bounding box join, I saved 28% processing time

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got it right, but I'd try this query:

```
SELECT
  props.mi_id,
  COUNT(1)
FROM (
  SELECT
    a.id,
    a.geom
  FROM (
    SELECT
      mi.id,
      mi.geom,
      ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Intersection(mi.geom, pp1.geom)), 3308)) area
    FROM mitch_ibra mi
    JOIN prop_p1 pp1 ON (ST_Intersects(mi.geom, pp1.geom))
  ) a
  GROUP BY
    a.id,
    a.geom
  HAVING SUM(area) > 50000
) props
JOIN hev ON (ST_Intersects(props.geom, hev.geom));
```

This gives you count of hev ids that intersect with mitch_ibra ids that intersect with prop_p1 and that intersection is > 50000.

If that's not what you're after, be a little more specific please. Sorry for potential typos, can't test the query without the tables.